# Azure Pipeline Angular Project Fails

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am learning how to work with Azure Pipelines, so I created a basic angular project and added it to the Git repo of my Azure project. However, my pipeline always fails on the "npm install and build" section of the YAML code, and I receive a "##[error]Bash exited with code '3'" error message. Here is what my YAML code looks like.

[image]

I didn't do anything specific with my pipeline, so I'm lost to why it's failing. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

In your 'package.json' file you have a section for 'scripts'. You can create you own values here. For example, I just created `"build-prod": "ng build --prod"` as you see below.

[image]

Now in your pipeline change `ng build --prod` to `npm run build-prod`

Comment: This fix my issue, so thank you for this! Unfortunately, now I'm getting a 254 exit code....
On to the next problem!